# How to fetch all the specific type files from storage in flutter

Tags: file, flutter

I am learning flutter and I want to know that how can I fetch all the specific types of files from the device storage. Suppose I want to get all the audio files with `mp3` extension files from the device storage in flutter then how can I achieve this?
I have tried searching for a good tutorial but could not find any good resources. I have also tried using the path provider package but can understand that in android how can I fetch from both local and external storage.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.
I would be grateful if u help me with some code also.
I am new to flutter development so please make my concepts clear.

Comment: Do you find out how can do this?